# Suggested edits that only changed the title will always show the current body

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When looking at a suggested edit that only changed the title, but not the body of the question, the review page will always show the *current* body and not what the body has been at the time of that edit.

For example [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4032897) only changed the title. As I wasn’t happy with what was done, I went to the question, and [edited it more](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21708130/revisions), changing both the title and the question body. However, when you look at the suggested edit, you can see the body I was editing in *after* the suggested edit. So the suggest edit does not really reflect the actually made changes.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for finding that :)